# How is the common Korean greeting, "have you had lunch?" spelled?

Tags: greeting, spelling

I'm working through Korean Pimsleur and they mentioned that a common greeting in Korean is "have you had lunch?", but I can't seem to find the correct spelling. It sounds like 점심 튜셨어요 or 점심 드셨어요.

Google Translate is no help at all, because it says both translate to "you had lunch"!

Comment: 드셨어요 is correct

Comment: There is no word `튜셨어요`... How could google translate that?

Comment: @LegenDUST google translate is wrong a lot of the time. 튜셨어요 is probably a common enough misspelling that it's auto learning algorithm has picked it up to mean the same as 드셨어요

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to say this, depending on who you're talking to and the level of familiarity with them!

> 밥은? = Food? (did you eat?)
>
> 밥 먹었어? = Did you eat (food)?
>
> 점심 먹었어? = Did you eat lunch?
>
> 점심 먹었어요? = Did you eat lunch? (to unfamiliar people)
>
> 점심 드셨나요? = Did you eat lunch? (to older people/unfamiliar people) but
>   using '나' here is a bit more friendly and I actually hear this  used
>   more in practice
>
> 점심 드셨어요? = The official 'Did you eat lunch?' to older
>   people/unfamiliar people

*keep in mind that I skipped the articles here (은/을) cause I never hear them used in speech